# Tkinter GUI failing to exit

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a code written and at the top in the file I have the option to Exit which closes the GUI. For some reason when I click "Exit" it doesn't exit. I feel as if there is a simple error that I made when writing this code, but I can't seem to find it. I hope another set of eyes might be able to do so.

```
#Import tkinter to make gui
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#Makes the GUI the same way it was at the beginning of the program

def login(*args):
    try:
        if (len(name.get())>=2) and (len(pw.get())>=2):
            name_entry.delete(0, END)
            pw_entry.delete(0, END)
            valid.set("")
        else:
            valid.set("Invalid!")
            pass
    except TypeError:
        valid.set("Invalid!")
        pass
    except ValueError:
        valid.set("Invalid!")
        pass

#Sets title and creates gui    
root = Tk()
root.title("Login")

topMenu=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=topMenu)
#Creates menu and submenus
subMenu=Menu(topMenu)

#Gives menu options
topMenu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)

#Configures column and row settings and sets padding
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

name=StringVar()
pw=StringVar()
valid=StringVar()

#Widgets asking name and age
name_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=15, textvariable=name)
name_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

pw_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=15, textvariable=pw)
pw_entry.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Username").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(N, W))
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Password").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=(N,W))
#ttk.Label(mainframe, text="                      ").grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=(E))

#Makes a button that clears everything and returns it to start of program
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Login", width=30, command=login).grid(column=2, row=3, columnspan=2, sticky=(W, E))

ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=valid).grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=(E))

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

name_entry.focus()
root.bind('<Return>', login)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When you say "For some reason when I click it it doesn't exit.", does "it" refer to the "Exit" item on the menu?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. Sorry if it was unclear.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Ran the above. Clicked "File" and chose "Exit". App exited cleanly. Python 3.5

Comment: Ah. I think it may be because I am using IDLE. I don't have a different compiler installed so I can't test my theory...

Comment: It works fine. This is an issue if you run GUI's in Idle, not when you run the same application from command (linux), or e.g. double click (Windows)

Comment: try changing `root.quit` to `root.destroy` to see if that works any better.

Comment: Yup that did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"try changing root.quit to root.destroy to see if that works any better." (Bryan Oakley)

This managed to do it. I don't know why but root.quit doesn't do it on idle.